# Custom exception on Service Response with Standard API

Tags: rest, exception

Using standard API, when i receive a POST, if things go wrong i must return an error response.

Since i'm not using a custom web service but a TriggerHandler, when one of the required parameters isn't in JSON POST, i'm using a custom exception to return a proper response. The problem is that the message shows the full stack trace.

Any way to deal with that?

**CODE**

```
private static void validateParams(List<CSVEnergyLead__c> lstToValidate){

    String strErrorMsg = null;

    for(CSVEnergyLead__c toValidate: lstToValidate){

        if(String.isBlank(toValidate.Stage__c)){
            strErrorMsg = 'Mandatory field Stage__c not found';
        }else if(String.isBlank(String.valueOf(toValidate.ClosingDate__c))){
            strErrorMsg = 'Mandatory field ClosingDate__c not found';
        }else if(String.isBlank(toValidate.Lead__c)){
            strErrorMsg = 'Mandatory field Lead__c not found';
        }

        if(!String.isBlank(strErrorMsg)){
            System.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR, 'Throwing excepction: '+strErrorMsg);
            throw new CSVEnergyLeadException(strErrorMsg);
        }
    }

}
```

**RESPONSE**

```
[{
    "message": "CSVEnergyLeadTrigger: execution of BeforeInsert\n\ncaused by: CSVEnergyLeadTriggerHandler.CSVEnergyLeadException: Mandatory field Stage__c not found\n\nClass.CSVEnergyLeadTriggerHandler: line 113, column 1\nClass.CSVEnergyLeadTriggerHandler.bulkBefore: line 32, column 1\nClass.TriggerFactory.execute: line 38, column 1\nClass.TriggerFactory.createHandler: line 26, column 1\nTrigger.CSVEnergyLeadTrigger: line 2, column 1",
    "errorCode": "CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY",
    "fields": []
}]
```

Comment: You can't modify the response...but on the caller side, surely your calling app isn't just dumping the stack trace for end users to see, is it? Take a look at the [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and perhaps edit the question.

Comment: What standard API call is your service using?

Comment: Excelent advise identigral I'll keep in  mind the X-Y problem. Rest API Bryan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use .addError on the record instead. This will show the relevant error without showing the full stack trace.